# Is Jeddict compatible for Netbeans 16?

Tags: netbeans

I am unable to install the Jeddict plugin on Netbeans 16.
I tried to install the jeddict plugin and a window with broken dependencies comes up. On the website it says minimum requirements as 15 but im not sure if 16 is compatible.

This isnt code related, I'm just trying to wonder if Jeddict is compatible with netbeans 16 or are my files corrupted

I tried to look up the related dependencies to install the dependencies but couldn't anything find them. I was expecting a clean installation

openjdk **version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20**
OpenJDK **Runtime Environment Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7)**
OpenJDK **64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)**

**Errors encountered while installing**

Some plugins require plugin Database Core to be installed.
The plugin Database Core is requested in implementation version 15-387759c96ce1b891ec45ffaf524a53499455fe1a.

The following plugin is affected:       jeddict

Some plugins require plugin Maven Embedder to be installed.
The plugin Maven Embedder is requested in implementation version 15-387759c96ce1b891ec45ffaf524a53499455fe1a.

The following plugin is affected:       jeddict
Some plugins require plugin Maven Repository Indexing to be installed.
The plugin Maven Repository Indexing is requested in implementation version 15-387759c96ce1b891ec45ffaf524a53499455fe1a.

The following
plugin is affected:       jeddict
Some plugins require plugin Maven Editor Model to be installed.
The plugin Maven Editor Model is requested in implementation version 15-387759c96ce1b891ec45ffaf524a53499455fe1a.

The following plugin is affected:       jeddict
Some plugins require plugin User Utilities to be installed.
The plugin User Utilities is requested in implementation version 15-387759c96ce1b891ec45ffaf524a53499455fe1a.

The following plugin is affected:       jeddict  Some plugins not installed to avoid potential installation problems.

As a very last resort i will do a fresh installation of openjdk and other linked stuff

Comment: @KGG The question is clearly on topic for Stack Overflow; it is about _"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_ Familiarize yourself with [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are hundreds of thousands of questions on IDE problems on Stack Overflow!

Comment: You need to update your question to state your Java version, and to detail the specific problem you encountered, including a screen shot of the actual error. Without those details your question may be closed.